# How to restore deleted favorites in chrome on windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, windows-8.1, bookmarks, chromium

A friend of me has a windows 8 laptop and Google Chrome as browser. She has deleted its favorites.
I know a file exists on Windows 7 in AppData : bookmarks.bak 
I looked on a Windows 8 laptop but i've only found the bookmarks file (with no .bak extension) in the folder Chromium in AppData/Local

Is there a solution to retrieve the favorites ?

Comment: If the file has not been replaced then file recover software is your best bet.  The restoration process is exactly the same as it was with Windows 7, so the file should be there, if its missing recovery is unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

In order to restore your deleted favorites in chrome you need to restore the previous file (P.S: YOU NEED TO TURN :

- Type in C:\Users\ then click your username, then AppData then Local, Google, Chrome, User Data and then Default.
- Locate the Bookmarks file - this is not a folder.
- Right click on Bookmarks
- Select restore to previous session
- Choose which date best suits your needs (CHOOSE WISELY) and click on it once and
  then click RESTORE not OPEN.
- A new window will open in order to confirm this you need to press
  Restore again.
- This should have restored your bookmarks to the correct day.
- Turn off the option of "Show hidden files"

Your Favorites will be back to normal :)